# Whatsapp Opt-in, Opt-in auditing

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

How do I ensure that I have the real user consent (explicit opt-in) about the receiving Whatsapp messages of our platform ? What's the informations do I need to persist in my database ?

Answer (score 0):

See below.

Getting Opt-in - WhatsApp Business API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/opt-in/

Comment: I've read the page already, but I still don't know how to let facebook know that I got consent from tje customer. How does Facebook check that? Do I need to store the opt-in in a separate database?